# Xamarin.Forms - How to disable Tab on TabbedPage?

Tags: xamarin

I'm looking for a way to disable a tab within a TabbedPage. The tab should be still showing up in the TabbedPage header but simply be disabled.

I tried to set the Page to IsEnabled = false but apparently this is not how you do it or I did it wrong. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom renderer for a tabbed page control and disable user interaction in your platform specific implementation of the renderer.

For example your renderer for iOS would use the `UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol` to override

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and return `NO` for the tab that should not be selectable. The solution for Android or Windows Phone would work similar.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my self-contained take on @joeriks method, which is a nice quick/simple solution.  Annoying that the event args are just EventArgs.

Just add this to your TabbedPage .cs file somewhere.

```
    Page _lastKnownPage;
    protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
        if (CurrentPage.IsEnabled)
            _lastKnownPage = CurrentPage;
        else
            CurrentPage = _lastKnownPage;
    }
```

Comment: This doe snot work for me since the OnCurrentPageChanged gets called over and over and crashes the app eventually.

Comment: in 2022 these is no more need for this snipped. IsEnabled property seems to work as intended